# how to call anonymous delegate dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, anonymous

I hava a delegate

```
public delegate void Context();
```

And i had implemented it by anonymous method,

```
public Context fakeHttpContext = () =>
        {
                ...
                create fake http context.
        };
```

I dont' want to execute the fakeHttpContext by

```
    fakeHttpContext.Invoke()
```

I wonder if i could invoke it by known the delegate name. is there anything in reflection likes:

```
    DelegateInfo info =     typeof(class).GetDelegate("fakeHttpContext");
    info.Invoke();
```

thanks

Comment: Could you provide also the when, where and why you would use that?

Answer (score 4):

Don't you find it a bit odd to try to retrieve **an anonymous method by name**? It's kind of a contradiction in itself.

That mere fact should give you a hint that what you're doing probably makes no sense. Just declare an standard method that implements the delegate or an event and invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is getting the field fakeHttpContext.
Assuming you class type is named MyObject :

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
Context context = (Context)(typeof(MyObject).GetField("fakeHttpContext").GetValue(obj));
context();
```

This is what you asked for, even if it's dirty... Reflection is rarely a good idea.